# How to choose the best classifier before tuning the hyperparameters?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, classification

I am training an ml model for a multi class classification problem. With that I train several classifiers (like xgboost, gradient boost, rf, extra trees, etc) each one doing the tunning of the hyperparameters with gridsearchcv.

Though likely to be multiclass, the time to train each model is taking several hours.

Can anyone help me with a good strategy to choose the best classifier before tuning the hyperparameters?

I thought of simply training each classifier without tuning the hyperparameters and seeing which one performs better and then picking the one that performs better to join the hyperparameters. It's a good idea?

Here's the code I use to train and tune the chosen model (in this example I used xgboost, but I did it for all the others mentioned, which took a long time).

```
# Maximum number of levels in tree
max_depth = [int(x) for x in np.linspace(10, 100, num = 4)]
max_depth.append(None)

param_grid = [
    {
        'reduce_dim__n_components': [0.7, 0.9, 0.1],
        'classify__learning_rate': [0.0001, 0.001, 0.01, 0.1],
        'classify__n_estimators': [int(x) for x in np.linspace(start = 100, stop = 1000, num = 4)],
        'classify__max_depth': max_depth
    }
]

grid_search = GridSearchCV(
    Pipeline([
        ('reduce_dim', PCA(svd_solver='full')),
        ('classify', xgb.XGBClassifier(objective='multi:softmax', n_jobs=-1))
    ]), param_grid, cv=5, scoring='accuracy', verbose=1, return_train_score=True, n_jobs=-1)
grid_search = grid_search.fit(train_prepared, y_train)
```

Comment: You need to search over model type and hyperparameters jointly -- otherwise you can miss a model type which is very good for a specific combination of parameters and not very good otherwise. My advice is to evaluate a lot of combinations of model type and hyperparameters, and then rank them by cross validation error.

Comment: Would it be putting all these models that I mentioned inside a pipeline and inside gridsearchcv with the tuning of the hyperparameters? It would take days :(

Comment: Well, the model + parameters combos are all independent, so you can run them in parallel, if you can arrange that. You could also do the cross validation split by selecting a small part for training and a large part for validation. Since you're searching for the best combo, it's not necessary to train on all the data; only enough to allow to compare model + parameters combos.